# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized using visual studio 15

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I caņ't seem to get around this error message: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

It refers to a `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
I'm not really sure what is going on, maybe the insert is not correct, but here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace md2
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MD2;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (izd_adr.Text != "" && izd_nos.Text != "") {
            cn.Open();               
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Publisher (pu_id, pub_name, adress) values ("+null+"'Elina', 'Kalnina')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("Ir pievienots");
            cn.Close();
            new Form1().Show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I followed a tutorial in how to do this, but I'm getting this error.
That Database looks like this: [image]

This seems like a easy mistake somewhere, but is really frustrating...

Comment: The error message says it all, you have't assigned the `Connection` property of the `Command` object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the connection property on the command object:

`cmd.Connection = cn;`

An easier way to manage this is to let the `SqlConnection` create the command, which associates the `SqlCommand` with the `SqlConnection`: ie

`cmd = cn.CreateCommand();`

Answer (score 0):

move `cmd.Connection = cn;` into the button click event. When you click the button currently, cmd has no connection property.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the SqlConnection to the SqlCommand, either with SqlCommand.Connection, pass it in the constructor or use CreateCommand().

I recommend creating a new SqlCommand and SqlConnection object when needed and refrain from caching them. SQL server does connection pooling anyway:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
  connection.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("....", connection))
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Connection String as given below If you are using Compact 4.0 Database

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MD2.sdf");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
```

you can change the Provider Name according to you SQL Server Name.

and Move **cmd.Connection = cn;** into the **button2_click** event.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with S. Laurijssen, and would like to emphasize that his example uses **using** blocks. Because **SqlConnection** and **SqlCommand** both implement **IDisposable**, each is automatically closed properly at the end of the block. My example put this in a class called **Common**.

My only, additional suggestion would be that you create a **public static** method that generates a **SqlConnection** object, opens it, and then returns the instantiated, opened connection. You can then do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = Common.GetConnection())
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[your SQL command here]", cn))
  {
  }
}
```

With this pattern, you do not need to remember to open or close your SqlConnection, and your code is cleaner.